# pivot table entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like dis

```
R_Id    M_ID      Y_ID  Value
100000  1          1    10
100000  1          2    20
100000  1          3    30    
100001  1          1    10
100001  1          2    20
100001  1          3    30    
100002  1          1    10
100002  1          2    20
100002  1          3    30
```

I want a pivoted result like

```
  100000   1   1    10  1    2    20   1   3   30
  100001   1   1    10  1    2    20   1   3   30
  100002   1   1    10  1    2    20   1   3   30
```

I am bit new to pivoting . Can anyone suggest me a query .

basically what i need is  , for all those duplicate R_Id , I need to show just one row and 
repeating rows as columns on right .
Note column numbers not fixed . It may change .

Comment: hi @Michał Powaga  , this works . but since the while loop is being used it may give performance issues i feel

Comment: Not in this case. Here while loop is used to create query **only** (that is executed at the end) not to process data row by row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If number of columns in result set is variable I would use dynamically build query. It's not optimized and maybe it's dirty way to do it but it works the way you want :-).

```sql
if object_id('tempdb..#t') is not null drop table #t

select * into #t from (
    select 100000 as r_id, 1 as m_id, 1 as y_id, 10 as val union
    select 100000, 1, 2, 20 union select 100000, 1, 3, 30 union 
    select 100001, 1, 1, 10 union select 100001, 1, 2, 20 union 
    select 100002, 1, 1, 10 union select 100002, 1, 2, 20 union 
    select 100002, 1, 3, 30
) t

if object_id('tempdb..#tab') is not null drop table #tab

select r_id, m_id, y_id, val, row_number() over (partition by r_id order by r_id, m_id, y_id) as row_num
into #tab
from #t

declare @qt int, @q nvarchar(max), @i int, @qj nvarchar(max)

select top 1 @qt = count(*) from #tab group by r_id order by count(*) desc

set @q = 'select t.r_id'
set @qj = ' from (select distinct r_id from #tab) t'

set @i = 1
while @i <= @qt
begin
    set @q = @q + ', t' + cast(@i as varchar) + '.m_id, t' + cast(@i as varchar) + '.y_id, t' + cast(@i as varchar) + '.val'
    set @qj = @qj + ' left join #tab t' + cast(@i as varchar) + ' on t' + cast(@i as varchar) + '.r_id = t.r_id and t' + cast(@i as varchar) + '.row_num = '
    if @i = 1 set @qj = @qj + '1'
    else set @qj = @qj + 't'+cast(@i -1 as varchar)+'.row_num + 1'
    set @i = @i + 1
end

set @q = @q + @qj

exec sp_executesql @q
```